# restart/power on usb port or modem?

Tags: 12.04, networking, usb, internet, usb-modem

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 . I will explain my situation first .

I am using A USB modem which frequently disconnect for an hour or so. Then i will plug off it from ports and will insert again .Then it will search again and connect .

My idea is , is there anything i can do else without plugoff the modem from USB ports , i mean restarting powersupply to modem or USB port .

One more point: I can't restart total USB's  power-supply because my speakers are USB and sometimes i used to work by attaching the USB devices .

Help me guys , if i got this then you are going to save me from an daily exercise .

Thank you .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [usb-modeswitch](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/usb-modeswitch) [image: Install usb-modeswitch]

We can try if a reset of our USB device helps resurrecting it. We first need to find out the vendor ID, and the product ID easiest by

```
lsusb
```

This will give information e.g. like follows:

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f9:0224 Brother Industries, Ltd
```

In this example the vendor ID is `04f9`, product ID is `0224` (right, its my printer).

To reset the device we may then issue

```
sudo usb_modeswitch -R -v <vendor ID> -p <product ID>
```

For more options read the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/usb_modeswitch.1.html) or the [project homepage](http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/).

[image: Install via the software center]

Comment: I have looked in synaptic , i got it installed already .

Comment: Sorry for that - now it should do.

Comment: Just a note - in case the modem hangs it may not even react on a reset command - but worth a try anyway.

Comment: hey , if device rstarted means again it have to ask me password of gsm sim but its not asking . i think its not doing . here is the link http://pastebin.com/qgDftJ8h

Comment: Sorry to read that. It did reset: `OK, device was reset`. If that did not help I have no really good further idea. I hope someone knows if it is possible to power-off an USB-port by software. I doubt it will work (e.g. my USB-ports here are always powered ON even when I powered my machine off).

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using *usbserial* driver to activate the usb modem, it's a [driver used for testing](http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-usb/msg45932.html)

Try the *option* driver

> USB driver for GSM and CDMA modems (USB_SERIAL_OPTION)
>
> CONFIG_USB_SERIAL_OPTION:
>
> Say Y here if you have a GSM or CDMA modem that's connected to USB.
>
> This driver also supports several PCMCIA cards which have a
>   built-in OHCI-USB adapter and an internally-connected GSM modem.
>   The USB bus on these cards is not accessible externally.
>
> Supported devices include (some of?) those made by:
>   Option, Huawei, Audiovox, Novatel Wireless, or Anydata.
>
> To compile this driver as a module, choose M here: the
>   module will be called option.
>
> If this driver doesn't recognize your device,
>   it might be accessible via the FTDI_SIO driver.

You can use it like this:

```
modprobe option
echo VENDORID PRODUCTID > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/option1/new_id
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a utility called [uhubctl](https://github.com/mvp/uhubctl) which makes this possible. (even with raspberry pi)

here is a sample usage:

```
sudo uhubctl -p 2 -a cycle
```